# Specifying values in stretched raster histograms of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, symbology, colormap

I am trying to use the stretched color option with a topography raster. I have a color bar that I painstakingly make in arc and I am basically trying to set values of the topography equal to certain colors using the histogram. The problem (I think) is the histogram doesn't have a break where I need it - it has a -40 then jumps to 19. I want a break at 0 so sea level will align with my shift from blue to green in my color bar.

Is there a way to set these values?
Or is there just a better way to do this altogether?

I would use classified color, however it doesn't seem to have a way of ramping the color between the bounds. Its just a single color for a range, and with only a maximum of 32 intervals it doesn't look very good.

Here is a picture of my best result using stretched. You can see the areas on the coast that are green.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You still want to used a stretched classification.  You can adjust the classification using the custom histogram settings:

[image]

You will have to play with the settings until you get the colors displaying the way you want.  Click the 'Histograms' button:

[image]

Here is an example - standard deviations vs my custom histogram:

Std Dev:

[image]

Custom histogram:

[image]